# ionic2 custom icon size and button size

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

Here is the sharing button, but icon size too big, I want it to be small

[image]

**.html** file

```
<ion-row>
  <button ion-fab color="wechat" (click)= "wechatshare(new)" small><ion-icon name="minan-wechat"></ion-icon></button>
  <button ion-fab color="danger" (click)= "weiboshare(new)"><ion-icon name="minan-weibo"></ion-icon></button>
  <button ion-fab color="primary" (click)= "qqshare(new)"><ion-icon name="minan-qq"></ion-icon></button>
  <button ion-fab color="wechat" (click)= "whatsappshare(new)"><ion-icon name="logo-whatsapp"></ion-icon></button>
  <button ion-fab color="facebook" (click)= "FBshare(new)"><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></button>
</ion-row>
```

.css file

```
.row .button-icon{
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}
```

This is what I did in css file, but still not working for me.

Thanks help and better help me design a beautiful share button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by 2 ways:

**1: override the CSS classes of ion-icon**

```
ion-icon {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

**2: Create a class inside ion-icon tag:**

```
.icon_size{
     font-size: 25px;
  }
```

In case if size is not decreasing. Try to use **!important**

```
ion-icon {
        font-size: 25px !important;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I tried used !important, icon size changed but button still big size

Answer (score 1):

Try to adjust the font size of the icon with the following code.

```
ion-icon {
  font-size: 14px; // Your size here
}
```

Comment: I tried this code just now, but still no changing for me

Comment: @YuyangHe Did you tried overriding it with !important ?

Comment: I tried used !important, icon size changed but button still big size

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use  `ion-icon{zoom:1.5}`
in css or scss for ionic 4+ version.